# How to backup a partitioned table in PostgresSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, database-partitioning

Is it possible to make a backup of a specific partitioned table with PostgreSQL 10?

When using:

```
sudo pg_dump -Fc -f "/home/schema.backup" -t schema.partitioned_table dbname
```

I am only getting the skeleton of the base table, without any values and without any partitions.

I also couldn't find anything in the extensive documentation.

Comment: Why should that be off-topic??

Comment: Maybe because it is about database administration and not about programming?

Comment: That worked, but listing all tables might be a bit cumbersome. If you'll post it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to use `-t` for all partitions.

This is probably a consequence of the design decision to have partitions visible as individual tables on the SQL level.