# How to backup a partitioned table in GreenPlum 5.18

Tags: greenplum, pg-dump

Is it possible to make a backup of a specific partitioned table with GreenPlum?

When using:

```
pg_dump -t schema.partitioned_table dbname >/tmp/tlb
```

I could get all partition tables with DDL if I exe my command on my GP's master node.

I could not get any partitions tables with DDL when I exe my command without my GP's nodes.

What should I do without my GP's nodes to get partition tables with DDL?

[pro on  pg 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973236/how-to-backup-a-partitioned-table-in-postgressql-10)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

The answer is GP's pg_dump is different from pg's pg_dmp.
Exe the command on GP's master node and any other pg nodes to see the different.

`pg_dump --help`